# Android: SQLite Connection returns null

Tags: java, android, sqlite, intellij-idea

I trying to connect SQLite.

```
public class Database {

private Statement stmt;
private Connection conn;

private final String DB_NAME = "db.sqlite";
private final String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.Simple_Diary/databases/";

public void Database()
{
    connect();
}

/**
 * Connect to the database
 */
public void connect()
{
    try {
        copyDataBase();
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC").newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {}
}

/**
 * Query
 * @param sql
 * @return ResultSet Result object
 */
public ResultSet query(String sql)
{
    try {
        return stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    }
    catch (SQLException | NullPointerException e) {
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * Copy database file from assets to "databases" directory
 */
private void copyDataBase()
{
    try {
        MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();

        InputStream mInput = ma.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int mLength;
        while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer)) > 0){
            mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
        }
        mOutput.flush();
        mOutput.close();
        mInput.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {}
}
```

}

```
 try {
        Database db = new Database();
        ResultSet rs = db.query("SELECT * FROM categories");

        String str = "its null!";

        if(rs != null) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                str += rs.getString("title") + "\n";
            }
        }
        dbtext.setText(str);
    } catch(SQLException e){
        dbtext.setText("err: " + e.toString());
    }
```

but variable "rs" returns null because variable "conn" returns null. I read many answers for the same problem in this site, but i could not fix this problem...
I'm using intelliJ. I added sqlite-jdbc jar as library, but it didnt help.

Comment: `public void Database()` doesn't look like `Constructor`, but more like `method`. Remove `void` and see what happens :-)

Comment: Check for instance this http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/ first - if you still have issues ... well, you know :)

Comment: This is not how you access SQLite in standard Android applications. Check [the official guide](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the class SQLiteOpenHelper.  This encapsulates a lot of work.  All you need to do is

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
{
  // put DDL here to create and init your tables, if needed.
}
```

Then use methods such as insertOrThrow, or rawQuery (query, args).

Let me know if you need more help.